# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure OSLCGenericAdapter/getUserAccessDataFWLSE0100E

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, maximo

I am using `IBM Worklight 5.0.6` with `IBM Maximo Anywhere 7.5.0`, with pre-installed Android applications "Work order approval" and "Work order Execution".

When opening one of the apps and providing the username and password, I receive the following error on the login page:

> Login failed because the information that is required for your user
>   could not be downloaded. Try to log in again. If the problem persists,
>   contact your system administrator.

When checking the log file, I find the following information:

```
[23.04.14 09:30:41:236 CEST] 0000002b TpaeCustomAut I  
processRequest() - Request
URI=/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkApproval/android/query

[23.04.14 09:30:41:250 CEST] 0000002b TpaeCustomAut I   processRequest() - Request
URI=/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkApproval/android/my_custom_auth_request_url

[23.04.14 09:30:41:251 CEST] 0000002b TpaeCustomAut I   getAuthenticationData() ... Entering

[23.04.14 09:30:41:282 CEST] 0000002b TpaeCustomAut I   processRequestAlreadyAuthenticated() ... Entering

[23.04.14 09:30:41:368 CEST] 0000002b TpaeCustomAut I   processRequestAlreadyAuthenticated() ... Entering

[23.04.14 09:30:41:370 CEST] 0000005a SystemOut     O OSLC query Start {"sessionid":"JSESSIONID=0000utzFBb1jU7JwC4OvvA4rODr:-1;
Path=\/","url":"http:\/\/dummyhost:000\/maximo\/oslc\/os\/oslcmaxuser?savedQuery=currentUser&oslc.select=*"}

[23.04.14 09:30:41:370 CEST] 0000005a SystemOut     O OSLC query display Path /maximo/oslc/os/oslcmaxuser

[23.04.14 09:30:41:376 CEST] 0000005a SystemOut     O OSLC retrieveUserInfo Start
{"totalTime":4,"isSuccessful":true,"responseHeaders":{"Cache-Control":"no-cache=\"set-cookie,
set-cookie2\"","Server":"IBM_HTTP_Server","Expires":"Thu, 01 Dec 1994
16:00:00
GMT","Location":"http:\/\/localhost\/maximo\/webclient\/login\/login.jsp?appservauth=true","Keep-Alive":"timeout=10,
max=100","Content-Length":"0","Content-Language":"de-CH","Date":"Wed,
23 Apr 2014 07:30:41
GMT","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Type":"text\/plain","Set-Cookie":["WASPostParam=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;
Path=\/maximo\/oslc\/os\/oslcmaxuser","WASReqURL=http:\/\/\/maximo\/oslc\/os\/oslcmaxuser;
Path=\/"]},"statusReason":"Found","responseTime":4,"statusCode":302}

[23.04.14 09:30:41:376 CEST] 0000005a InvocationCon E  logError FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure
OSLCGenericAdapter/getUserAccessDataFWLSE0100E:  parameters:{
"arr": [
{
 "sessionid": "JSESSIONID=0000utzFBb1jU7JwC4OvvA4rODr:-1; Path=\/"
}
]
}

null
FWLSE0101E: Caused by: null
```

Any ideas?

References:

- [IBM Maximo Anywhere](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v49r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/overview/c_sys_architecture.html)
- [IBM Maximo Anywhere & Worklight](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/maximo_anywhere_7_5_is_available?lang=en)

Comment: What is IBM Anywhere? Add links to your question...

Comment: You can find Information here:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v49r1/topic/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/overview/c_sys_architecture.html

Comment: Can you please check two things: 1) that the adapter is deployed. 2) that the Worklight server has access the the backend it is trying to access through the adapter (I think that the issue is here).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Below my answers:
1) The Adapter called OSLCGenericAdapter is deployed, connectivity Information looks fine
2) How do I test that? When I call the URL http://<servername>:80/maximo/oslc/Login, I can perform a login to Maximo Asset Managment application (Remark: I can use the same user as I use for the android app log in and it is successful). Do I need to test anything else?

Comment: It may not be related to IBM WorkLight or Maximo Anywhere. There is a bug with Maximo 7.x (7.1 to 7.5.x) as far as I know, where the sessionid cookies are not properly handled when you try to re-login. I don't know if you can set the URL for Maximo Anywhere, but ideally, you want to try http://maximo:9080/maximo/ui/ (at least from a workstation).

Answer (score -1):

You can try to clean application cache & data of your Android apps. Personally, I use an emulator and i have to clean it each time I want to launch apps otherwise it doesn't work.

I already had this error, but I had so much errors with Anywhere, I don't remember what I did each time :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I can confirm, that the cache & data needs to be removed for each log in. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. Any other hints? Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you did build.cmd all-gen, all-dist and especially all-deploy, you didn't have any error about your adapter ? As says ravidor in comment, it seems to be a connexion problem with database

Comment: no, all three commands end with the message "BUILD SUCCESSFUL". I am using DB2 V9.7.

Comment: Are you trying with a navigator or a real Android Smartphone (or emulator) ? Because I have the same message when i try with chrome, but works fine on emulator

Comment: Thank you. I just found out (based on your hint) the following:
1) Opening the Android App with Google Chrome Browser throws the message as described (Login failed because[...])
2) Opening the Android App with a real Smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S4, Android 4.4.2, Kernel 3.4.0-481100) and Google Chrome Browser is the same result.
3) Opening the Android App gives the following result: the login with my test user "works" and I am redirected to a page with says "Provide your Password, which you used last time for the applcation login. If you do not have this Password, you have to reset the app.

Comment: I also read somewhere that Android version must be >4.1 and 4.4 is not supported. For my emulator, I use API 18 Android 4.3.3. Maybe it's the reason it doesn't work on your Smartphone

Comment: I now used an Android Emulator with Android API-18 and I receive the same error message.